# Buffer overflow this and run multiplication instead of addition?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num1;
int num2;
int res;

static int add(void) {
    res = num1 + num2;
    printf("\nAnswer: %u", res);
}

static int sub(void) {
    res = num1 - num2;
    printf("\nAnswer: %u", res);
}

static int mal(void) {
    res = num1 * num2;
    printf("\nAnswer: %u", res);
}

static int div(void) {
    res = num1 / num2;
    printf("\nAnswer: %u", res);
}

void do_operator() {

    char op[1];

    printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /):");
    scanf("%s", &op);

    if (*op == '+')
    {
        add();
    }
    else if (*op == '*')
    {
        mal();
    }
    else if (*op == '-')
    {
        sub();
    }
    else if (*op == '/')
    {
        div();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNo valid input: %s", op);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("\nEnter number-1:");
    scanf("%u", &num1);
    
    printf("\nEnter number-2:");
    scanf("%u", &num2);
    
    do_operator();
    return 0;
}
```

Hey, I’m new to buffer overflow exploits. I’m trying to run this code and when giving input instead of the addition function running `+` run the multiplication function `\*` using buffer overflow. I have tried multiple different but non prevailed

Buffer overflow exploit the give code to execute multiplication function `\*` but the operator given is addition function `+`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &op);` says read a string and write it to `op`. A string has at least 1 readable character and the NUL terminator at the end, e.g., 2 characters. `op` has only space for 1. Why don't you just use `char op; scanf(" %c", &op);`? `%c` reads one character, which is what you want.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &op);` is your target to overflow. `"%s"` without a *field-width* modifier will attempt to write as many characters to the address of `op` as you enter, overflowing as soon as you exceed the storage of `op`. (which is why filling a string with `"%s"` is no safer than using `gets()`) See. [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/3422102) So you have your target -- now you need to know how many bytes you need to overflow to get to `mal()`.

Comment: You also need to fix your conversion specifier types (e.g. `"%u"` to `"%d"` or type type from `int` to `unsigned`. You need to either change your function types to `void` or add `return res;`.

Comment: See [How to do string buffter overflow with scanf function?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/244249)

Answer (score 0):

The code has undefined behavior for multiple reasons:

- you do not test the return values of `scanf()`, so invalid input will not be detected.
- the functions `add`, `sub`, `mal`, `div` are defined to return an `int` value but the code does not have `return` statements.
- you pass a 1 byte array for `%s` which will cause a buffer overflow unless at end of file. Furthermore, `&op` does not have the expected type for `%s`. A more reliable way to input the operation is

  ```
    if (scanf(" %c", op) == 1) {
        /* operation was read as a single character */
    } else {
        /* unexpected end of file or input error */
    }
  ```

It is very difficult to exploit these flaws to make the code call `mal()` instead of `add()`, but here is an example where invalid input will appear to use multiplication instead of addition:

```
Enter number-1:0+ 1

Enter number-2:Enter an operator (+, -, *, /):
Answer: 0
```

Comment: How would `0+ 1` make `0` and `1` appear in their respective variable though? Aren't you actually doing `0` -> num1, `+` -> oops scanf fails, `num2` remains untouched (zero). 0 + 0 = 0.

Comment: @Lundin: yes, your analysis is correct, the second `scanf("%u", &num2);` will fail, return `0` and leave `num2` unchanged, hence still zero as `num2` is an uninitialized global variable thereby initialized to zero in its type. The third `scanf` will read the `+` and store a null terminator beyond the end of the `op` array (undefined behavior ignored for the purpose of this example). The function `add` will be called and perform `0 + 0` producing and printing `0`.